Laravel precognition using alpinejs not working with alpine.data()
I have followed the official doc of Laravel Precognition and it is working fine if I define x-data as shown there.
Below is Working Example
<x-app-layout title="Roles" is-sidebar-open="true" is-header-blur="true">
    <main class="main-content w-full px-[var(--margin-x)] pb-8">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4 py-5 lg:py-6">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-medium text-slate-800 dark:text-navy-50 lg:text-2xl">
                Add New Role
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card p-4 sm:p-5 space-y-4">
            <form x-data="{
                    form: $form('post', '/validate/roles/create', {
                        name: '',
                    }),
                }" method="POST" action="{{ route('manage.roles.store') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-3">
                    <x-forms.inputs.text label="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                    <h2
                        class="font-medium tracking-wide text-slate-700 line-clamp-1 dark:text-navy-100 lg:text-base sm:col-span-3 col-span-1">
                        Permissions
                    </h2>
                    <div class="sm:col-span-3 col-span-1">
                        <x-forms.inputs.multiple-switches name="permissions" :options="$permissionsOptions" valueField="name"
                            labelField="name" :selected="old('permissions', [])" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-end space-x-2  mt-4">
                    <x-forms.inputs.submit label="Save" icon="fa fa-save" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
</x-app-layout>


Below is NOT Working Example
But I want to make small change so the code looks better, Below is my code.
<x-app-layout title="Roles" is-sidebar-open="true" is-header-blur="true">
    <main class="main-content w-full px-[var(--margin-x)] pb-8">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4 py-5 lg:py-6">
            <h2 class="text-xl font-medium text-slate-800 dark:text-navy-50 lg:text-2xl">
                Add New Role
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card p-4 sm:p-5 space-y-4">
            <form x-data="validateForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('manage.roles.store') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-3">
                    <x-forms.inputs.text label="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                    <h2
                        class="font-medium tracking-wide text-slate-700 line-clamp-1 dark:text-navy-100 lg:text-base sm:col-span-3 col-span-1">
                        Permissions
                    </h2>
                    <div class="sm:col-span-3 col-span-1">
                        <x-forms.inputs.multiple-switches name="permissions" :options="$permissionsOptions" valueField="name"
                            labelField="name" :selected="old('permissions', [])" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-end space-x-2  mt-4">
                    <x-forms.inputs.submit label="Save" icon="fa fa-save" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
                Alpine.data('validateForm', () => ({
                    form: $form('post', '/validate/roles/create', {
                        name: '',
                    }),
                }));
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
</x-app-layout>


I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $form is not defined here when trying to use like this. In the normal case as mentioned in the official doc it is working. I am on alpinejs version 3.
I have tried looking for solutions but didn't get much reference.

In AlpineJs, to access to magic properties and methods from javascript, you need to reference them using the this qualifier:
Alpine.data('validateForm', () => ({
    form: this.$form('post', '/validate/roles/create', {
        name: '',
    }),
}));

Here you can find the related documentation
EDIT
Custom "magics" are not available when the data-object is created, but can be used in the init() function.
This should work:
Alpine.data('validateForm', () => ({

   form: null,

   init: function () {

       this.form = this.$form('post', '/validate/roles/create', {
           name: ''
       })
   }
}));


Thanks for the reply @tupkap but this is not working also. I had tried this before.
Alpine Expression Error: this.$form is not a function

I have added some new informations to my answer
